# How to compare two patterns efficiently in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, pattern-matching

```
pattern 1: [(0,1)(2,4)] => [(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)] 
pattern 2: [(0,1)] => [(2,3)(4,5)]
```

In my definition `pattern 2` is a subpattern of `pattern 1`, since `(0,1)` of `pattern 2` is contained by `(0,1)(2,4)` of `pattern 1` and `(2,3)(4,5)` of `pattern 2` is contained by `(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)` of `pattern 1`.

What is appropriate and efficient algorithm to implement this comparison? Thanks:)

Comment: The typical approach would be to compare the left and right separately.  For each side, sort the lists and do a parallel walk to find matching items.  This isn't really a C++-specific question though.

Comment: What kind of data structures hold these patterns?

Comment: Is this correct : A pair "matches" another pair if both elements are equal. A list of pairs L1 is a "sublist" of another list of pairs L2 if every pair in L1 matches another *unique* pair in L2, not necessarily in the same sequence. A pattern P1 is a "subpattern" of P2 if each list in P1 is a sublist of the *corresponding* list in P2.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually: Compute the [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) of the pattern1 and pattern2, and check whether it is equal to pattern2.

Actually: You want to test whether pattern2 is a substring of pattern1. This can be done faster via a single scan of both strings.

Comment: it's not a substring, see `(2,3)(4,5)`

Answer (score 0):

Trivial: Each character of pattern2 appears in pattern1, and in the same order. A trivial check up front is that length(pattern2) <= length(pattern1), therefore this is O(length(pattern1)). This is optimal since all characters must be considered.